# A South African English teacher (Austrian descent) said we have to use "go back home", not "come back home"? Is he right?

Tags: word-usage

There is a South African English teacher (Austrian descent) said we have to use "*go back home*", not "*come back home*"?

**Is he right?**

I think South African English is different & maybe they have heir own styles.

Comment: I think rather that South African English teachers of Austrian descent have their own styles.

Comment: There is a tendency in certain dialects in the US to interchange "come" and "go", as well as "bring" and "take".  The inversion doesn't occur in every context, but often with reference to "home".  (I haven't studied what specific cues result in this inversion.)  (But what @grizzly says is the "correct" way to use the terms.)

Comment: By the way, are you sure the teacher is Austrian? Or Australian? As far as I know Austrians speak German. Of course, he can be an English teacher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine these 2 situations;

You and your mother is at home. You are going to leave soon for a party and your mother says;

- Come back home early.  (She will not say go back home early)

After this, you went to the party. You enjoyed and you want to leave, You say your friend;

- I should go back home early.

It depends on your location.